# Spinning Wheel - animation function keeps going even the spin is stopped

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript function and canvas and an animation function to spin the wheel(roulette kind of spinning wheel).

When the spin is stopped, I was trying to see what prize I got. that part worked fine.

Now, i am passing that prize to another function, from where I want to send that prize name to the backend.But when I am trying to `console.log` prize, I am getting an correct details but it goes through infinite loop as my function keeps going yet.

Here is the function :

```
(function anim() {
    deg += speed;
    deg %= 360;

    // Increment speed
    if(!isStopped && speed<3){
        speed = speed+1 * 0.1;
    }
    // Decrement Speed
    if(isStopped){
        if(!lock){
            lock = true;
            slowDownRand = rand(0.994, 0.998);
        } 
        speed = speed>0.2 ? speed*=slowDownRand : 0;
    }
    // Stopped!
    if(lock && !speed){
        var ai = Math.floor(((360 - deg - 90) % 360) / sliceDeg); // deg 2 Array Index
        ai = (slices+ai)%slices; // Fix negative index
        // return alert("You got:\n"+ label[ai] ); // Get Array Item from end Degree
        submitEntry(label[ai]);    
    }

    drawImg();
    window.requestAnimationFrame( anim );
}());
```

I think I know the reason `window.requestAnimationFrame(anim)` keeps calling the function again and again and only the condition of `lock and !speed` getting true, but function keeps going on and on.

How can I stop the function or break the function or come out of the function once the spin is stopped?

Comment: Where do you set `isStopped`?  I don't see any code to set it to true.  Perhaps it just speeds up forever (Increment speed block) and never calls the Decrement Speed block because you never set isStopped to true.

Comment: Did you mean to `return` in the end of `if (lock && !speed)` condition? Another thing to mention: I hope you understand that any user can affect this script or just `submitEntry` with whatever he wants. So, may be it is a good idea to make back-end choose a winner and then just draw an animation which will actually stop on the chosen one. Last thing to mention: I would personally do this with CSS animations: add `.rotating` class, which spins the wheel pin; then set `rotate` 2D transform and slow down the animation with another CSS class.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev doesn't `lock` stay `false` all the time under this code since the if clause to set it to `true` is dependent on a never set `isStopped`?

Comment: @aviya.developer Yeah, I mean, did the OP mean to return in **any** place of his code, so that `requestAnimationFrame` isn't called again? This condition just seemed to be the proper part, because it contains this `submitEntry` to back-end logic :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yup i think you are right. It sends the data back and should return and stop there probably.

Comment: As @YeldarKurmangaliyev commented, you need to use `return` after `submitEntry`. This is because if you don't, it will run the function `submitEntry` as you have specific but when it is done then it will proceed to call `drawImg()` and `requestAnimationFrame` again and again indefinitely because it is not told to stop, which is what `return` would do.